# Binding to Frame's SourcePageType doesn't work in Windows store App

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-store-apps

Here's the XAML of the Frame:

```
<Frame Name="HostingFrame" SourcePageType="{Binding HostFramesource, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and in my viewModel here's the code:

```
//The current Page to be loaded in the view
private Type hostFramesource;
public Type HostFramesource
{
    get 
    {   

        return hostFramesource; 

    }
    set 
    {
        hostFramesource = value;
        SetComboBox();
        OnPropertyChanged("HostFramesource");
    }
}
```

I know that binding itself works, because the whenever the setter is called the getter is called afterwards. but apparently the property  `SourcePageType` always stays null for some reason.

I can imagine that setting such a property would need more work or something as it creates a new instance of the page that should be hosted inside this frame but I have no clue what to do regarding that.

Comment: How about instead of binding - pass the reference to the frame or a navigation service wrapper to your vm and simply call `Navigate()`?

Comment: The frame doesn't navigate, it's within the page itself. but an alter is to have a wrapper to navigateFrame() it's okay, but that wasn't the workaround I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just addition of "Mode=TwoWay" fixed this problem for me.

```
<Frame SourcePageType="{Binding CurrentPageType, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```